# unable to statically build mpich

Tags: mpi, cross-compiling, static-linking

I'm trying to cross compile MPICH and statically link libraries using the following commands:

```
export CC="/buildroot-2015.02/output/host/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc"
export CFLAGS="-march=armv5te -I/buildroot-2015.02/output/host/usr/include/"
export LDFLAGS="--static -L//buildroot-2015.02/output/host/usr/lib/"
./configure --prefix=/mpich-3.1.3/build/ --host=arm-linux  --disable-shared --with-pm=hydra --with-device=ch3:nemesis --disable-fortran
```

After building I tried `file mpiexec` and I got the following:

> mpiexec: symbolic link to `mpiexec.hydra'
>   $ file mpiexec.hydra
>   mpiexec.hydra: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped

I want know how to link MPICH statically.

Comment: what about ``ldd mpiexec.hydra`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux yes I have libmpi.a in the lib folder .
the result of ldd mpiexec.hydra:
not a dynamic executable

Comment: Well, if `ldd` tells you `not a dynamic executable`, you've reached your goal, congratulations

Comment: No, I'll take it back. If it is cross-compile, and your native `ldd` is different from target, you'll get no dependencies. Ok, next thing to try is `readelf`. Basically, you should check if your app required any shared libs. `readelf` should work on non-native bins. Something along the line `readelf -a mpiexec.hydra | grep NEEDED`

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux I have tried `readelf -a mpiexec.hydra | grep NEEDED`  
 
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libnsl.so.0]  
  
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]  
  
0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libm.so.0]    

0x00000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libc.so.0]    

I think that the problem is in the buildroot generated files

Comment: yes, it is clearly shared executable depending on several shared libraries